# Find first truthy value returned from some predicate over a range

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost

With a `vector<T> v;` and some `bool f(T);`

`std::any_of(v.begin(), v.end(), f);` tells us if any element satisfies `f`

`std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), f);` tell us which element satisfies `f`

But let's say I have `std::optional<U> g(T)`

I'd like to get the first result of the predicate `g` applied to the `[v.begin(), v.end())` where the result `has_value()` (aka, is true-ish).

I've rougly written it out like this:

```
template <typename Iterator, 
  typename Callable, 
  typename ResultT = std::invoke_result_t<Callable, typename Iterator::value_type>>
auto first_true(Iterator b, Iterator e, Callable && op) {
    static_assert(static_cast<bool>(ResultT{}) == false, 
        "The default-constructed value returned by Callable must be convertible to boolean and evaluate to 'false'");

    ResultT res{};
    for (b; b != e; b++) {
        res = op(*b);
        if (res) return res;
    }
    return res;
};
```

But would much rather use a `std` or `boost` function.
Is there a standard or boost library function that returns the first "truthy" value returned from the predicate?

Comment: Use `find_if` like `std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const auto& val) { return g(val).has_value(); });`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for replying, but that doesn't do what I'm looking for. Like I said, I don't want an element iterator, I don't want true/false, I want exactly the result of `g()` that first has a 'truthy' value.

Comment: `std::copy_if` would satisfy this, if it is acceptable that all elements are checked instead of stopping after the first match is found.  Related - your "`std::find_if` tells us which element satisfies `f`" actually tells you _the first_ element which satisfies `f`.

Comment: @DrewDormann I prefer the short-circuit behavior that `find_if` and `any_of` provide. In my use-case, I have a list of validators, all returning a `std::optional<validation_error>`. The first validation failure terminates and surfaces the error.

Comment: Is calling `g` twice on found value problematic?

Comment: @Jarod42 it could be if `g` is expensive or has side-effects. Currently my `g`s are pure and cheap, but that could change in the future.

Comment: `auto it = std::find_if(..); if (it != v.end()) { return g(*it); }` would do the job for pure & cheap `g`, else I *"fear"* that you have to stay with your version (without `std`).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not what you want in the std::library as single function.

There are many possible solutions by combining functions from the algorithm library.

But I would go with your solution. That is probably the best.